# C Pointers are Reverting to Old Address in Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

There are 3 linked lists, 2 of which (headX and headY) are given in descending order, and the functions job is to sort them into a single list (headZ).

For some reason, the algorithm works fine, but when its done and its going back through the recursion, the 3 pointers revert to their old values as they go "back" through the recursion.

```
void SortedMergeRecur(Node* headX, Node* headY, Node* headZ)
{
    if (headX == NULL && headY == NULL)
        return;

else if (headX == NULL && headY != NULL)
{
    if (headZ == 0)
    {
        headZ = headY;
        headY = headY->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        headZ->link = headY;
        headY = headY->link;
        headZ = headZ->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }

    SortedMergeRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}

else if (headX != NULL && headY == NULL)
{
    if (headZ == 0)
    {
        headZ = headX;
        headX = headX->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        headZ->link = headX;
        headX = headX->link;
        headZ = headZ->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }

    SortedMergeRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}

if (headX != NULL && headY != NULL)
{
    if (headX->data > headY->data)
    {
        if (headZ == NULL)
        {
            headZ = headY;
            headY = headY->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            headZ->link = headY;
            headY = headY->link;
            headZ = headZ->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (headZ == NULL)
        {
            headZ = headX;
            headX = headX->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            headZ->link = headX;
            headX = headX->link;
            headZ = headZ->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
    }
    SortedMergeRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}
}
```

I know that parts of this could be simplified (like appending the whole list if either headX or headY are null) but I wrote it this way because I thought it might fix the problem, which it didn't....

Comment: What did you expect? It sounds like you wanted to pass the pointers by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are copied by value the same way that variables are:

```
void test(int x)
{
    x = 5;
}
int y = 3;
test(y);
//y is 3
```

Same idea:

```
void test(int* x, int* y)
{
    x = y;
}
int a = 5; int b = 6;
int* x = &a;
int* y = &b;
test(x, y);
//x is still &a and y is still &b
```

If you want to change pointers, you have to pass pointers to the pointer:

```
void test(int** x, int *y)
{
    *x = y;
}
int a = 5; int b = 6;
int* x = &a;
int* y = &b;
test(&x, y);
//x is now &b and y is still &b
//(note that a and b are still 5 and 6, respectively)
```

Since you're using C++, another option is to pass by reference:

```
void test(int*& x, int *y)
{
    x = y;
}
int a = 5; int b = 6;
int* x = &a;
int* y = &b;
test(x, y);
//x is now &b and y is still &b
//(note that a and b are still 5 and 6, respectively)
```

Comment: pointer pointers! i didnt even know those existed. thanks so much!

Comment: @user1732919 For C++, you're probably better off using a reference to a pointer.  Pointers to pointers can look nasty very quickly.  There are though, times when I find a pointer to a pointer less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify parameters and keep those changes outside the function, you need to pass them by reference - for example

```
void SortedMergeRecur(Node*& headX, Node* headY, Node* headZ)
//                         |      
//                 pass by reference
```

If you modify `headX` inside the function, the changes will persist after it returns. Changes to `headY` and `headZ` won't, because they are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in C, **arguments are always passed by value**, never by reference.

When you pass a pointer to a function like

```
  void SortedMergeRecur(Node* headX, Node* headY, Node* headZ)
```

if you change (i.e. set) the formal pointer argument `headX` inside the body of your `SortedMergeRecur` the actual pointer argument used in the call is not affected.

If you want to affect them in the function body so that their setting is propagated to the caller, declare the formals pointers to pointers, like

```
  void SortedMergeRecur(Node** pheadX, Node** pheadY, Node** pheadZ)
```

then set inside the body:

```
   *pheadY = (*pheadY)->link;
```

In C++ you can have formal arguments passed by reference with `&`